# How to load angularJs V1.8 custom element as web component into Angular V17.1 using @angular-architects/native-federation

Tags: angular, angularjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have created one Angular MFA Architecture app which have shell and remote apps which build on top of Angular V17.1. I have to create this below mentioned shell/host app routing to access AngularJS V1.8 with module federation custom element which exposed in "http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js" as web component and i can see the js code while hit this remote url. we are using Native federation  because of ng v17 use esbuild instead of webpack in angular V17.1.

When we route with angular V17 and native-federation, it was not working and throw below error to access angularjs application http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js as mentioned below, but i can see file exposed javascript file while hit this same url in browser. there is no more cors issue and i can find one error while tried to access route through MFA shell app.

[image]

[image]

This is NG v17 MFA app route to access angularjs remoteEntry.js

```
{
path: 'angularjs',
loadChildren: () =>
  loadRemoteModule({
    remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js',
    remoteName: 'angularjs',
    exposedModule: './web-components',
  }).then((m) => m.helloComponent),
},
```

app\app.module.mjs // Custom Element in a angularjs@1.8.3

```
angular
  .module("app", []).component("helloComponent", {
    controller: function () {
      this.message = "Hi i'm from AngularJS!";
    },
    template: `
          <h1 style="color:#000">
            {{$ctrl.message}}
            <img src="https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angularjs/AngularJS-Shield.svg" height="30">
          </h1>
        `
  })


export class MfeAngularJs extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const root = document.createElement("hello-component");
    this.appendChild(root);
    // angular.bootstrap(root, ["app"]);
  }
}

customElements.define("angularjs-element", MfeAngularJs);

//bootstrap the app
angular.element(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```

webpack.config.js in angularjs@1.8.3

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  //create entry point for the application
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  stats: {
    children: true
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "img/[name][ext]"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
              publicPath: "/fonts/"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".mjs", ".json"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "app/Content/img", to: "img" },
        { from: "app/fonts", to: "fonts" },
        {
          from: "app/**/*.html",
          to: ({ context, absoluteFilename }) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(context, absoluteFilename);
            const newPath = path.join(
              path.dirname(relativePath),
              path.basename(absoluteFilename)
            );
            return newPath.startsWith("app") ? newPath.slice(4) : newPath;
          },
          noErrorOnMissing: true,
          globOptions: { ignore: ["**/index.html"] }
        }
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./app/index.html"
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "angularjs",
      library: { type: "var", name: "angularjs" },
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./web-components": "./app/app.module.mjs"
      },
      remotes: {
        // For remotes (please adjust)
        angularjs: "http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js"
      },
      shared: []
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    // contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true, // this is needed for SPA routing
    port: 4203,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://api-qa.abc.com",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  }
};
```

index.js // entry point in angularjs@1.8.3

```
require("./app/app.module.mjs");
```

Comment: You have one BIG issue in your code: The Angular Router loads ONLY Angular components. So I suppose you created your Web Component using the "createCustomElements" from "@angular/elements". If you have not used that API, I highly recommend it. Now, you exposed your Web Component in your federation file. Now If you want to use that Web Component, here is what you have to do. First, in your Shell app, create a wrapper component for your Web Component. Second, your routing config now import that wrapper component as you would import a standard component, no lazy loading. That's the first part.

Comment: Your wrapper component in your Shell app imports whatever you have exposed in your MF federation file. Now check that your federation file is exporting the "bootstrap.ts". That file should create the AppComponent for your MF and register that class to the browser. The tag for your MF should NOT be the same as the tag for your AppComponent. Remember to update your "index.html" of your MF with the tag you define for your MF when it loads to the browser. Otherwise, you'd see an empty screen when running your MF.

Comment: Now, if you are using Angular V17, I'd use just Stand Alone components, no NgModules at all. When you are using Web Components inside and Angular App, the NgZone should be Singleton. That means, you should inject NgZone to your Shell and MFs as Singleton. Check this link for more info https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/micro-frontends-with-modern-angular-part-2-multi-version-and-multi-framework-solutions-with-angular-elements-and-web-components/